# Maven: How to create a jar file of source files and test files?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project that also includes unit tests. I want to create a JAR file from both code files placed under 'src' folder and code files placed under 'test' folders. Currently, I use maven-jar-plugin:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-a-jar</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>make-a-test-jar</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

This plugin generates two jar files - one file for source and another one for tests. I want to create one Jar file for both.

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to do this? There may be better alternatives.

Comment: OK. So can you elaborate such an alternative?

Comment: Why do you want to have your src files in test directory? - It look like not good practice

Comment: Not unless I know what you want to achieve.

Comment: @CrazySynthax Without further information, it will be very hard to help you. What is the "real" problem that you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate jar file only [from the `src/test` area in your project](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

That will create a separate jar file which can be used by other like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

But usually if you like to have a separate test-jar it makes more sense to create a separate project/module which contains the source code and you only change the scope of the dependency. This is described in the docs as [the preferred way.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html#The_preferred_way) which I strongly recommend to go.